# Can't change color of my model suit, not because i don't have viewport shading on

Tags: color

Please help my suit I made won't change colors no matter what I do.
This is an image:[image: HELP]
This is the file: https://pasteall.org/blend/5b4ffc731c4643868345fce984becb4d

Comment: hello could you please share your file (upload and copy paste the URL)? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/5b4ffc731c4643868345fce984becb4d this is the file

Comment: I’ll check the file, but right now this looks *correct.* The suit is white but in a dimly lit environment. Set the Base Color to orange or something, then show us the screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

Your suit has about 10 materials assigned to it, and these do not show up in the Materials tab because you entered 'felt' in the material search entry. Clear the search entry, remove all material slots except the one you want, and take it from there.